# Does CosmosDB's Mongo Aggregation pipeline support `maxTimeMS`?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

TL;DR: Cosmos seems to ignore the `maxTimeMS` option.

I'm working with a fairly large partitioned CosmosDB collection (a few million documents) using the MongoDB API and have found that some aggregations are timing out after ~10 seconds. I can query fine with very small windows (i.e. very specific match criteria) but if I match 50k+ documents queries timeout. If it's relevant, I'm using default indexes added by Cosmos.

I've tried passing the `maxTimeMs` (30s) and setting various other timeout options on my Mongo client but to no avail.

For reference I'm using the C# Mongo driver and here's the command:

```
{
  "aggregate" : "MyDocuments",
  "pipeline" : [{
      "$match" : {
        "Created" : {
          "$gt" : ...,
          "$lt" : ...
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$QueryTerms",
        "Count" : {
          "$sum" : 1
        },
        "FooCount" : {
          "$max" : "$Foo.Count"
        },
        "Bar" : {
          "$first" : "$Bar"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "$sort" : {
        "Count" : -1
      }
    }],
  "maxTimeMS" : 30000.0,
  "cursor" : { }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on since you omitted all the details of your pipeline elements. Also: Did you enable indexes for the properties you're using? Have you tried limiting the return set size? Please edit to be more specific, as right now it's very broad (and off-topic, as written).

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon, I've edited accordingly. Yes, if I limit the match set quite drastically my queries return successfully (although slower than I would like). I have default indexes, the ones added by Cosmos. My main concern is that my timeouts aren't being honoured by Cosmos.

Comment: @Harry I have experienced very similar behavior when using the Mongo API with Cosmos. I know from reading their documentation and talking with their support that they only have a subset of the Mongo API implemented. Were you ever able to find a better solution than using specific match criteria?